# Stripe API; How to create test connect account successfully?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe connect and I have trouble making connect account for just testing. Basically some fake data is invalid so I cannot make any test connect account. Is there an easy way or kind of fake info for creating test connect account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. First, when using [Standard](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) accounts, you don't need to enter any information in the account application form. As long as you use your development client application id `ca_XXXX` then you would see a link at the top of the form during the OAuth flow that reads "Skip this account form". This lets you bypass the activation form and connect the account to the platform.

Otherwise, you can use [Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) accounts to create test accounts via the API with fake/test information to test your integration.

Comment: I'm using standard account. So does it mean I just need to save the data like stripe_connect_id while skipping the form? But how can I see the platform which is connected to the main Stripe?

Comment: Actually I can see the connected standard account on my main page.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A little late to the party, but @koopajah do you know if it's possible to create standard accounts **with** charges and payouts enabled? I can create accounts fine through the oauth workflow, however once they're connected and their emails are confirmed, I'm stuck with ID verification. However on their documentation they state that uploading any image, while testing, should confirm the account...

Comment: Standard accounts should work fine even in Test mode. I'd recommend discussing this with Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Please note while the "Skip this account form" is a great option, it will create an account in your country (determined by IP/browser info?) so it is useless if you try to test flows with other zones as Stripe Connect behaves different depending on it.

Comment: You can easily change the country during the OAuth flow though, right at the top there's a country dropdown!

Comment: where do I pass this client_id to? mentioned here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#using-oauth

Comment: Can I use client_id together with one time onboarding URLs returned by Stripe API?

Comment: @DmitryMugtasimov i'm also stuck unable to find where to enter this `client_id`, i can't seem to pass it in the `accountLink.create` sdk method, and the test mode standard account onboarding does not offer a way to skip the onboarding :/

Comment: There's no reason to use the `client_id` at all in that case. The `client_id` is the `ca_123` and is only used for OAuth. If you use AccountLinks, you never need this.

Answer (score 1):

To test a Connect account you have to:
 1. Create a Stripe Connect account (using some `email_address_A`)
 2. Then create a second, non-Connect account (using some `email_address_B`)

From the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#creating-accounts):

> You can create any type of test account you need: Standard, Express, or Custom. You can also create multiple test accounts, e.g., representing multiple countries.
>
> **You should not connect the platform account to itself, as that fails
>   to reflect the real world use of Connect, and makes debugging
>   challenging.**
>
> To test the OAuth flow for connecting another account, create a new
>   Stripe account using another email address and then take that new
>   account through the OAuth flow. This works for both Standard and
>   Express accounts.
>
> To test Express accounts without providing a real phone number, use
>   `000 000 0000` as the phone number and `000-000` as the SMS code when
>   prompted.
>
> You can create Custom test accounts using the code on the Custom
>   Accounts page. The account does not need to be activated because it
>   can’t be used for live charges.
>
> ### Using OAuth
>
> To easily test an OAuth integration, the development client_id allows you to:
>
> - Set your redirect_uri to a non-HTTPS URL
> - Set your redirect_uri to localhost
> - Force-skip the account form instead of having to fill out an entire account application (Standard accounts only)
> - Get test access tokens for connected users

Comment: Thanks for copy pasting, however, this does not provide informations on how to actually create the account (where do I find the actual form to connect?)